# Python subprocess (using Popen) hangs indefinitely and doesn't terminate when the script ends. Why, and how to fix?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

When I run the parent script without forking into the subprocess, it terminates fine at the end. When I run the subprocess script by itself, it terminates just fine at the end.

However when I run the subprocess script inside of the parent script as a subprocess as needed, instead of terminating at the end, it just hangs indefinitely. Any ideas why this happens?

Here's the parent script code -- with the subprocess execution code being in the move_current_image function:

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import subprocess

image_folder = r'C:\Users\anton\Pictures\image_editing\CURRENT IMAGE FOLDER' # the folder path of the images to curate
requires_editing_folder = r'C:\Users\anton\Pictures\image_editing\REQUIRES IMAGE EDITING'

files = os.listdir(image_folder)
files_index = 0

root = tk.Tk() # creates a simple GUI window
root.geometry('800x600')

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

scrollbar_v = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar_v.pack(side="right", fill="y")
scrollbar_h = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)
scrollbar_h.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_v.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbar_h.set)

frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor='nw')

label = tk.Label(frame)
label.pack()

zoom_state = False
img = None

# Functions for mousewheel scrolling
def scroll_v(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta)), "units")
canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", scroll_v)

def scroll_h(event):
    canvas.xview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta)), "units")
canvas.bind_all("<Shift-MouseWheel>", scroll_h)

# Functions for keyboard scrolling
def scroll_up(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(-5, "units")

def scroll_down(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(5, "units")

def scroll_left(event):
    canvas.xview_scroll(-5, "units")

def scroll_right(event):
    canvas.xview_scroll(5, "units")

def load_next_image(): 
    global img
    global files_index
    if files_index >= len(files):
        messagebox.showinfo("Information", "No more images left")
        root.quit()
    else:
        img_path = os.path.join(image_folder, files[files_index])
        img = Image.open(img_path)
        update_image_display()
        files_index += 1

def delete_current_image(): # deletes the current image and loads the next one
    global files_index
    img_path = os.path.join(image_folder, files[files_index - 1])
    os.remove(img_path)
    files.pop(files_index - 1)
    files_index -= 1
    load_next_image()

def update_image_display(): # toggles zoom in, zoom out
    global img
    if zoom_state:
        tmp = img.resize((img.width, img.height)) # 100% size
    else:
        tmp = img.resize((int(img.width*0.4), int(img.height*0.4))) # 40% size
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(tmp)
    label.config(image=photo)
    label.image = photo

    # Updating scroll region after image is loaded
    root.update()
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

def toggle_zoom(event): # toggles zoom state pt 2
    global zoom_state
    zoom_state = not zoom_state
    update_image_display()

def move_current_image():
    global files_index
    img_path = os.path.join(image_folder, files[files_index - 1])
    new_path = os.path.join(requires_editing_folder, files[files_index - 1])
    os.rename(img_path, new_path)

    subprocess.Popen(["python", "pixelbin-image-transformation-v3.py", files[files_index - 1], requires_editing_folder], 
                     start_new_session=True)

    files.pop(files_index - 1)
    files_index -= 1
    load_next_image()

# Bind the keys to the desired events
root.bind('<Right>', lambda event: load_next_image()) # approves this image, moves to next
root.bind('<Left>', lambda event: delete_current_image()) # deletes this image, as it doesn't meet the criteria
root.bind('<Up>', lambda event: move_current_image()) # moves this image into "requires photoshop editing" holding bay folder
root.bind('e', toggle_zoom) # bounces back between 100% and 40% zoom

# keyboard-based scrolling, for maximum efficiency
root.bind('f', scroll_down)
root.bind('r', scroll_up)
root.bind('d', scroll_left)
root.bind('g', scroll_right)

load_next_image() # start the workflow
root.mainloop() # start the GUI main loop
```

Here's the subprocess script code:

```
import sys
import os

# STEP 1 = UPLOAD IMAGE FILE TO PIXELBIN
# DOCUMENTATION FOR API-BASED FILE UPLOADING: https://github.com/pixelbin-dev/pixelbin-python-sdk/blob/main/documentation/platform/ASSETS.md#fileupload

CurrentImageFilename = sys.argv[1] # this will be files[files_index - 1] from the parent script, which gets passed into this script as a variable
CurrentImageFolder = sys.argv[2] # this will be image_folder from the parent script, because this is run as a subprocess
CurrentFilepathFull = os.path.join(CurrentImageFolder, CurrentImageFilename)
FinalImageDownloadFolder = r"C:\Users\anton\Pictures\image_editing\IMAGE EDITING COMPLETED"

import asyncio
from pixelbin import PixelbinClient, PixelbinConfig

config = PixelbinConfig({
    "domain": "https://api.pixelbin.io",
    "apiSecret": "my_api_key_goes_here",
})

pixelbin:PixelbinClient = PixelbinClient(config=config)

try:
    print("Pixelbin image upload in progress...")
    result = pixelbin.assets.fileUpload( # sync method call (there's also an async method, in the above documentation)
        file=open(CurrentFilepathFull, "rb"),
        path="IMAGE_EDITING_FOLDER",
        name=CurrentImageFilename, # uses the unique filename each time since I may be running transform operations in parallel. doing so on identical filenames, before deleting the previous, would absolutely cause timing problems.
        access="public-read",
        tags=["tag1","tag2"],
        metadata={},
        overwrite=True,
        filenameOverride=True)
    print("Image uploaded successfully!")
    # print(result)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# Pixelbin automatically modifies filenames like so. I therefore follow their convention so I can later delete the correctly-formatted filename.
FilenameModifiedByPixelbin = CurrentImageFilename.replace('.', '_') 

# STEP 2 = RUN TRANSFORMATION ON SPECIFIED IMAGE
# DOCUMENTATION FOR URL-BASED TRANSFORMATIONS: https://www.pixelbin.io/docs/url-structure/#transforming-images-using-url, https://www.pixelbin.io/docs/transformations/ml/watermark-remover/

# this basically auto-runs the transformation if you submit the properly formatted URL;
# instead of literally navigating to the URL, this executes the same functionality via background HTTP GET requests
# in this case, the cloud-name is functionally like the API key that allows it to be authenticated

def auto_delete_original_image_from_storage(): 
    # STEP 3 = AUTO-DELETE ORIGINAL IMAGE FROM PIXELBIN STORAGE, POST-TRANSFORMATION + DOWNLOAD
    # DOCUMENTATION FOR API-BASED FILE DELETION: https://github.com/pixelbin-dev/pixelbin-python-sdk/blob/main/documentation/platform/ASSETS.md#deletefile
    
    print("Pixelbin image deletion from storage in progress...")
    
    try: # I don't redefine the config stuff / permissions here, because that was done earlier during fileUpload
        result = pixelbin.assets.deleteFile( # sync method call
            fileId=f"IMAGE_EDITING_FOLDER/{FilenameModifiedByPixelbin}")
        print("Image deleted from Pixelbin storage!")
        # print(result)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

import requests
import time

def fetch_image(url):
    print("Pixelbin image transformation in progress...")
    response = requests.get(url)

    # continues functionally "refreshing" the CDN URL until the transformation is complete and the image is ready for download
    # note that this does NOT continue to fire additional identical jobs + use up credits each time
    # that's because once the exact specific job is sent via the specific "send job" URL? it simply runs until completed
    # and you'll get a 202 code that simply says: "that job is currently in progress, please wait..."
    # by "rerunning" it after fully completed too? it'll just auto-download the already-completed image, not re-run the original job
    while response.status_code == 202: # status code 202 = transformation still in progress;
        print("Transformation still processing. Waiting for 5 seconds before trying again.")
        time.sleep(5)
        response = requests.get(url)

    if 'TransformationJobError' in response.text:
        print("There was an error with the transformation.")
        return None

    if response.status_code == 200: # status code 200 = successful image transformation, ready for download;
        filepath = os.path.join(FinalImageDownloadFolder, CurrentImageFilename)
        with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
        print("Image downloaded successfully!")
        auto_delete_original_image_from_storage()
        return True

    print(f"Unexpected status code: {response.status_code}")
    return None

url = f"https://cdn.pixelbin.io/v2/my_api_key_goes_here/wm.remove(rem_text:true)/IMAGE_EDITING_FOLDER/{FilenameModifiedByPixelbin}"
fetch_image(url)
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did also find this Reddit thread on a similar issue:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1vbie0/subprocesspipe_will_hang_indefinitely_if_stdout/

"Subprocess.PIPE will hang indefinitely if stdout is more than 65000 characters."

"The problem is in the communicate function. It silently fails when the subprocess passes too much data through either the output or error pipes. When communicate stops reading from the parent end of the pipe, the pipe fills and blocks writes at the child end."

Could this be the issue? I don't explicitly try to communicate back and forth between the subprocess and parent script, however the subprocess does download an image file (which would be quite large in this case), and perhaps that similarly exceeds some kind of memory limit that then causes it to hang indefinitely like in the above example?